# Angular how not to send OPTION when sending auth token in HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

Having an issue with CORS, trying to do a `GET` request with `Authorization` token but having an issue with OPTIONS. Wondering how to not send OPTIONS when requesting `GET` to another server?

```
$http({
        url: request_data.url,
        type: request_data.method,
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('Auth'),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        crossDomain: true
    }).then(function(response) {
        //process your data here
        vm.prodData = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

I can't send a request because the CORS issue, probably due to the header `Authorization` part.

Comment: Not possible in your case.

Comment: $http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

`Authorization` headers are not "safe", so you can't include them in a cross origin request without permission.

The [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) is there to ask for permission.

You are doing something unusual that is a potential risk, so you have to change the server you are making the request to so it will tell the browser that it is OK to make the request.

Comment: So its server side matter than client side then I supposed.

Answer (score -1):

Is far as i know when youre trying a CORS request it will always send an OPTIONS request first to check if youre allowed to make requests, you have to deal with that on server side, for instance in php i do the following:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" );
    exit();
}
```

that way if the client send an OPTIONS request it will automaticly send an 200 OK response and then it will wait for the correct request (GET, POST, etc)

Comment: "when youre trying a CORS request it will always send an OPTIONS request" — It won't. Simple requests are not preflighted.

Comment: "send an 200 OK response and then it will wait for the correct request" — A 200 OK response is insufficient for permission to be granted. You need to send appropriate CORS headers too (such as Access-Control-Allow-Origin … which can't be wildcarded for a preflighted request).

Comment: I know about it but his question its refering to what can he do to deal with the options request, not the entire cors